# WordPress. Не отображаются изменения в шаблоне, сделанные через ftp

Tags: wordpress

Начал работу над новым проектом на wp, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При редактировании шаблона через ftp не отображаются изменения, а при редактировании кода шаблона через админку - все работает.

Кэш браузера очищал, кэш плагина тоже. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А как вы через ftp редактируете файлы?

Comment: Например есть шаблон header.php, я его выкачиваю, локально редактирую с помощью sublime text и закачиваю обратно на хостинг

Comment: Что вы называете кешем плагина? Какого плагина?

Comment: Тогда у вас всего несколько вариантов. Первый — реально ли вы загружаете файл на севрер по ftp? Загрузите по ftp, после откройте в админ-панели. Если изменений нет, то скорее всего дело в ftp-программе. Если изменения есть, то проверьте как они отображаются на сайте. Если их нет, то скорее всего так работает кэш WordPress. Если у вас maxcache, то сбросьте по ссылке. Если wpsuper, то лучше его временно отключите (на этап отладки), поскольку он вносит правки в .htaccess и браузер отображает страницу из своего кэша, а не реальную на сайте.

Comment: Фтп был от другого сайта, но абсолютно единичного по содержанию. Понял я это когда установил плагин через админку, а в папке plugins изменений не было. Спасибо всем кто откликнулся